# Opening a port on CentOS server not working externally?

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, port, node.js

I am trying to to setup a Ghost blog instance on port 80 of my CentOS 6 virtual server. There are no pre-installed web servers occupying port 80.

If I run Ghost in production mode as a background operation, I can curl it via localhost and 127.0.0.1 as expected but I have no luck with the external ip address. This behavior persists whether or not iptables has rules written into it.

Here is my `netstat -ntl` output:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9249/node           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2261/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6009/postmaster     
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      2261/sshd           
tcp        0      0 ::1:5432                    :::*                        LISTEN      6009/postmaster
```

Perhaps it is just my lack of expertise for server configuration but I cannot figure out how to get port 80 open over the internet.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you forwarded your modem/router port 80 to your CentOS LAN IP?

Comment: This is a Linode server. Network equipment configuration is not in my control. Everything is handled through my Linux environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Ghost is only bound to localhost, not listening globally. In order to accept traffic from any address, the http server needs to be bound to 0.0.0.0:80, 
as in this example:

`Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Could you post the content of your config files?

(posting as an answer, due to insufficient points to comment)

Comment: Using 0.0.0.0 in the host ip configuration worked. I am not sure why this is not stated in the Ghost docs.